# Extend existing wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if I could extend a existing wordpress plugin. For example adding some new features but without touching the original plugin files. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I found the solution. For example in woocommerce plugin, I need to add some html to the sigle product so I wrote in function.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_single_product_my_custom_function', 15 );

function woocommerce_single_product_my_custom_function(){
echo '<p>this is my html code</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unless the original defines hooks to extend, I am afraid this will not be possible. I suggest the way you would do that is copy the plugin directory and give it a different name in its definition

Comment: I found the solution. I did a add_action to a plugin existing action and added all my logic on it. This way my code is executed from template function.php file and the plugin keeps clean.